# Laravel 8 hasManyThrough not returning data

Tags: laravel, pivot, has-many-through, has-many

I have 3 tables that are all Eloquent Models. I'm attempting to use a hasManyThrough, or a pivot, or such to get a relationship from origin table to the last table. I have a hasManyThrough setup now, but Im not getting any results. The query from a dd() looks to be correct as far as the query is built-out, but I don't see any data. There are no errors being thrown.

Tables and ids:

```
users:
id

apps:
id
user_id
app_id

appversions:
id
app_id
user_id
```

A user can have many apps. An app can have many versions. I would like to get all versions for a particular user from all of their apps they own. The only one difference is the versions table is called 'appversions' and the model is called version.

I am setting the table name as such on the version model.

```
class Version extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'appversions';
}
```

On my User model, I am attempting this hasManyThrough

```
public function versions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Models\Version', 
            'App\Models\App',
            'user_id',
            'app_id',
            'id',
            'app_id'
        );

    }
```

And then calling it from my controller like so:

```
$userVersions = $user->version();
```

Comment: Why does `apps` table have an `app_id` column?

Comment: unfortunately I do not manage the db tables. The app_id is a separate ID created for the apps. Something like "aa111". The app_id in versions references that and not the primary incrementing key. That's why I'm specifying new keys with the hasManyThrough.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and seeing it now.

I changed this:

```
$userVersions = $user->version();
```

To this:

```
$userVersions = $user->version;
```